# Getting Blockchain Domains From Transaction Hashes

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, golang

I am compiling a list of some blockchain domains (.eth, .crypto, etc.) and was wondering what would be the best approach.

My strategy is to take something like this:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xb485d89aba096fc9f117fa28b80dc8aac7971049

which is the wallet for Unstoppable Domains, who are one of the blockchain domain registrars. I understand that their wallet doesn't have all of the blockchain domains, as there are other registrars, but it's a good start. I can write up a scraper to grap the transaction hash for each of these transactions, but here's where I'm stuck:

Would it even be possible to pull the domains from the transaction hash if decoded? If not, is there any other method that might work? If it is possible, then how might I go about doing that? I've tried so many things in Golang, which is what I would prefer to use, but to no avail. I've already tried all of the stuff in go-ethereum, but the posts on here regarding decoding transaction hashes in go-ethereum are outdated, so you have to dig through the current source code and try and see how to decode the data. Is there also a JavaScript solution? Would web3js do what I'm looking for? Again, I would *prefer* to use Golang, but I'll use whatever is necessary.

In short, how do I decode a transaction hash in Golang? (Or JS if necessary)

Thanks for your time!